# system.collections.generic.IEnumerable Error

Tags: c#, arrays, list, decimal

I have this class

```
Сlass Orderbook
{
public List<decimal[]> Bids { get; set; }
public List<decimal[]> Asks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make an insert, like this

```
orderbook.Bids.InsertRange(i, Convert.ToDecimal(e.LastOrder.Changes[0][0]));
```

but I get an error
Can not convert from decimal to system.collections.generic.IEnumerable []
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a List of arrays. The `InsertRange` requires a "range", like an `IEnumerable<T>`. In your case the type (T) is an array:

So, to not make it more complicated: this should work:

```
orderbook.Bids.Insert(i, new decimal [] {Convert.ToDecimal(e.LastOrder.Changes[0][0]}));
```

---

What I would do is the following:

Use a list of decimals (not the array):

```
class Orderbook
{
    public List<decimal> Bids { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Asks { get; set; }
}
```

And add a bid like this:

```
orderbook.Bids.Insert(i, Convert.ToDecimal(e.LastOrder.Changes[0][0]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. For me,    it worked.orderbook.Bids.Insert(i, new decimal[] { Convert.ToDecimal(e.LastOrder.Changes[0][1]), Convert.ToDecimal(e.LastOrder.Changes[0][2]) });

Comment: I have too little reputation

Comment: No worries... ;-)